# Compare two text files and output the elements that are different

Tags: java, algorithm, text-files

I am writing a program to do a basic degree audit. I want to read a curriculum text file and a transcript text file. Each file has 3 columns the department "CPSC", course number "1710", and the number of credits "3". A course is the dept, course number, and credits. How do I compare the "courses" in the transcript file to the"courses" in the curriculum file. Then store the "courses" that are different into a new arrayList and output the new arrayList.

```
class Audit 
 {
    private ArrayList<Course> curriculum;
    private ArrayList<Course> transcript;

    public Audit(String curriculumFilename, String transcriptFilename) 
     {
        curriculum = readCourses(curriculumFilename);
        transcript = readCourses(transcriptFilename);
     }

public ArrayList<Course> degreeAudit() {
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList();
    for(Course course : transcript) 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < curriculum.size(); i++)
        {
                if (!(curriculum.get(i).getDept().equals(course.getDept()) && 
                   (curriculum.get(i).getNumber().equals(course.getNumber()) )))
                        courses.add(curriculum.get(i));                  
        }

    }
    return courses;   
}

public void displayCurriculum(String msg) 
{
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println(curriculum);
}

public void displayTranscript(String msg) 
{
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println(transcript);
}

/*
    Read ALL course information from the given filename.
    Each line of the filename must be in the format:  String  String  int
    For example:            CPSC  2740  3
*/
private ArrayList<Course> readCourses(String filename) 
{
    ArrayList<Course> courses = new ArrayList();      
    File file = new File(filename);
    try 
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            Course courseTemp = new Course();
            courseTemp.set(scanner.next(), scanner.next(), scanner.nextInt());
            courses.add(courseTemp);
        }
        scanner.close();
    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return courses;

}
```

}

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
         if(rhs == null) return false;
         if(rhs == this) return true;
         if(!(rhs instanceof Course)) return false;

         Course crse = (Course) rhs;
         if(!dept.equals(((Course)rhs).dept)) return false;
         if(number!=((Course)rhs).number) return false;
         if(credits!=((Course)rhs).credits) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It looks like you're comparing every course to every transcript.  That doesn't seem like what you want to do.  Did you intend just to compare course 1 to transcript 1, course 2 to transcript 2 and so on?  Honestly, it's not very clear what you want - you haven't exactly asked a question.

Comment: No, I apologize for not being clear. Both curriculum and transcript text files has dept, course number, and credit. My question is how do I compare the "courses" in the curriculum text file to the "courses" in the transcript file. @azurefrog

Comment: If you have access to the `Course` class I'd write an `equals()` method for it.  If not I'd write a `CourseComparator`.

Comment: How can I use this equals() method towards the degree audit? @azurefrog

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from the code is that you are taking one course at a time from transcript and then matching it to all the courses in the curriculum. If is does not match on the basis of the three entities, then you add it to the list courses.

Well, I can surely tell you one thing that this will give you all the files in the transcript, that are not in curriculum, but it won't give you the files , that are there in curriculum but not in transcript. Is that what you want?

Also, I am not sure what you are trying to do with the equals method. Instead of doing

```
curriculum.get(i).getDept().equals(course.getDept())
```

shouldnt you be doing

```
curriculum.get(i).equals(course)
```

and pass this equals the course that you want to compare it with. And in your Course class, you override the equals method. In the equal method, you just compare the two courses on the  basis of `dept, number and credits`, that I think you are already doing.